Getting unnecessary special characters in Url while encoding and decoding json with rawurlencode
I am trying to send JSON array of image URLs to a second page but my redirection URL has a lot of special characters which might be slashes, spaces, etc.
I have tried both 'urlencode' and 'rawurlencode' but the problem is the same. Here is the part of the code:
if (!empty($images)) {
            $encoded_urls = rawurlencode(json_encode($images));
            // Generate the redirect URL
            $redirect_url = add_query_arg([
                'urls' => $encoded_urls,
                'type' => 'image',
            ], site_url('/display-document/'));

            // Log the redirect URL for debugging
            error_log("Redirect URL: " . $redirect_url);

            // Send the JSON response with the redirect URL
            wp_send_json_success([
                'redirect_url' => $redirect_url
            ]);
        } else {
            error_log("No images found.");
            wp_send_json_error('No document found for the given details.');
        }

And here is how I am decoding the response:
$documentUrls = isset($_GET['urls']) ? json_decode(rawurldecode($_GET['urls']), true) : []; 
$documentType = isset($_GET['type']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['type']) : '';

This is what I am getting as URL:
https://checkvisaonlinenow.com/display-document/?urls=%5B%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fcheckvisaonlinenow.com%5C%2Fwp-content%5C%2Fuploads%5C%2F2024%5C%2F08%5C%2Fconverted_images%5C%2Fimage-66cb2563608de-0.jpeg%22%2C%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fcheckvisaonlinenow.com%5C%2Fwp-content%5C%2Fuploads%5C%2F2024%5C%2F08%5C%2Fconverted_images%5C%2Fimage-66cb2568a92f2-0.jpeg%22%2C%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fcheckvisaonlinenow.com%5C%2Fwp-content%5C%2Fuploads%5C%2F2024%5C%2F08%5C%2Fconverted_images%5C%2Fimage-66cb2569293a8-1.jpeg%22%5D&type=image

Please can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Read about percent encoding: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/asr_5000/21-28/ecs-admin/21-28-ecs-admin/m_http-url-encoding.pdf

when you json_encode the url, it automatically escapes characters like / with a backslash and when you rawurlencode the json string, it encodes these backslashes as %5C. Thats why you're seeing them in the resulting  ulr. use $encoded_urls = rawurlencode(json_encode($images,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)); and try once

I was unable to remove the characters by any method so I sent the URL directly without 'urlencode' or 'rawurlencode' and it worked fine.

Care to share which methods you tried?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
